# Response.body with jest-express

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, jestjs

When using package `jest-express` to mock Requests in a Typescript project, what is the correct way to ensure that `req.body` is an object and not a string?

When a requests's body is parsed to JSON with `express.json()`, the value of `req.body` is replaced with the parsed Javascript object, but the `Request` type from `jest-express` has `string` as the type of the body property.

Is there some Typescript way of 'changing' the type?

How to get the `Request` type from `jest-express` to have a `body` property of type `any` or `object`?

**Bonus question:**

The `Request` type from `jest-express` does not seem to be a direct replacement for `Request` from `express`. I have to do something like this:

```js
middlewareFn(<express.Request> <unknown> request, <express.Response> <unknown> response)
```

to cast from the `jest-express` types to the `express` types when using the `jest-express` mocks as arguments in the tested functions.

How to use `jest-express` types as direct replacements for `express` types?